# Attempting Unauthorized operation - SQL 2008 R2 install

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I've been banging against this for a few days.  Keep getting this unauthorized error when trying to install SQL 2008 R2 on a Windows 7 machine.  I've changed permissions on the key, does not fix...  Created an admin user, gave specific permissions on that key, does not fix...  Disabled all firewalls, installed from a local admin, does not fix...  I'm out of patience and ideas!  :)  Help?

```
2012-07-06 13:09:11 Slp: Sco: Attempting to set value AppName 
2012-07-06 13:09:11 Slp: SetValue: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VSTAHostConfig\SSIS_ScriptComponent\2.0, Name = AppName 
2012-07-06 13:09:11 Slp: Sco: Attempting to create base registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, machine  
2012-07-06 13:09:11 SSIS: Processing Registry ACLs for SID 'S-1-5-21-2383144575-3599344511-819193542-1074' 
2012-07-06 13:09:11 Slp: Sco: Attempting to open registry subkey SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\100 
2012-07-06 13:09:11 SSIS: Setting permision on registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\100. 
2012-07-06 13:09:11 Slp: Sco: Attempting to replace account with sid in security descriptor D:(A;OICI;KR;;;S-1-5-21-2383144575-3599344511-819193542-1074) 
2012-07-06 13:09:11 Slp: ReplaceAccountWithSidInSddl -- SDDL to be processed:  D:(A;OICI;KR;;;S-1-5-21-2383144575-3599344511-819193542-1074) 
2012-07-06 13:09:11 Slp: ReplaceAccountWithSidInSddl -- SDDL to be returned:  D:(A;OICI;KR;;;S-1-5-21-2383144575-3599344511-819193542-1074) 
2012-07-06 13:09:11 Slp: Sco: Attempting to set security descriptor D:(A;OICI;KR;;;S-1-5-21-2383144575-3599344511-819193542-1074) 
2012-07-06 13:09:11 Slp: Sco: Attempting to normalize security descriptor D:(A;OICI;KR;;;S-1-5-21-2383144575-3599344511-819193542-1074) 
2012-07-06 13:09:11 Slp: Sco: Attempting to replace account with sid in security descriptor D:(A;OICI;KR;;;S-1-5-21-2383144575-3599344511-819193542-1074) 
2012-07-06 13:09:11 Slp: ReplaceAccountWithSidInSddl -- SDDL to be processed:  D:(A;OICI;KR;;;S-1-5-21-2383144575-3599344511-819193542-1074) 
2012-07-06 13:09:11 Slp: ReplaceAccountWithSidInSddl -- SDDL to be returned:  D:(A;OICI;KR;;;S-1-5-21-2383144575-3599344511-819193542-1074) 
2012-07-06 13:09:11 Slp: Sco: Attempting to normalize security descriptor D:(A;OICI;KR;;;S-1-5-21-2383144575-3599344511-819193542-1074) 
2012-07-06 13:09:11 Slp: Sco: Attempting to replace account with sid in security descriptor D:(A;OICI;KR;;;S-1-5-21-2383144575-3599344511-819193542-1074) 
2012-07-06 13:09:11 Slp: ReplaceAccountWithSidInSddl -- SDDL to be processed:  D:(A;OICI;KR;;;S-1-5-21-2383144575-3599344511-819193542-1074) 
2012-07-06 13:09:11 Slp: ReplaceAccountWithSidInSddl -- SDDL to be returned:  D:(A;OICI;KR;;;S-1-5-21-2383144575-3599344511-819193542-1074) 
2012-07-06 13:09:11 Slp: Prompting user if they want to retry this action due to the following failure: 
2012-07-06 13:09:11 Slp:
---------------------------------------- 
2012-07-06 13:09:11 Slp: The following is an exception stack listing the exceptions in outermost to innermost order 
2012-07-06 13:09:11 Slp: Inner exceptions are being indented 
2012-07-06 13:09:11 Slp:  2012-07-06 13:09:11 Slp: Exception type: Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.Sco.ScoException 
2012-07-06 13:09:11 Slp:     Message:  
2012-07-06 13:09:11 Slp:         Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation. 
2012-07-06 13:09:11 Slp:     Data:  
2012-07-06 13:09:11 Slp:       WatsonData = 100 
2012-07-06 13:09:11 Slp:       DisableRetry = true 
2012-07-06 13:09:11 Slp:     Inner exception type: System.UnauthorizedAccessException 
2012-07-06 13:09:11 Slp:         Message:  
2012-07-06 13:09:11 Slp:               Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation. 
2012-07-06 13:09:11 Slp:         Stack:  
2012-07-06 13:09:11 Slp:                 at System.Security.AccessControl.Win32.GetSecurityInfo(ResourceType resourceType, String name, SafeHandle handle, AccessControlSections accessControlSections, RawSecurityDescriptor& resultSd) 
2012-07-06 13:09:11 Slp:                 at System.Security.AccessControl.NativeObjectSecurity.CreateInternal(ResourceType resourceType, Boolean isContainer, String name, SafeHandle handle, AccessControlSections includeSections, Boolean createByName, ExceptionFromErrorCode exceptionFromErrorCode, Object exceptionContext) 
2012-07-06 13:09:11 Slp:                 at Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.Sco.SqlRegistrySecurity..ctor(ResourceType resourceType, SafeRegistryHandle handle, AccessControlSections includeSections) 
2012-07-06 13:09:11 Slp:                 at Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.Sco.SqlRegistrySecurity.Create(InternalRegistryKey key) 
2012-07-06 13:09:11 Slp:                 at Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.Sco.InternalRegistryKey.GetAccessControl() 
2012-07-06 13:09:11 Slp:                 at Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.Sco.InternalRegistryKey.SetSecurityDescriptor(String sddl, Boolean overwrite) 
2012-07-06 13:09:11 Slp:
---------------------------------------- 
2012-07-06 13:09:24 Slp: User has chosen to retry this action 
2012-07-06 13:09:24 Slp: Sco: Attempting to normalize security descriptor D:(A;OICI;KR;;;S-1-5-21-2383144575-3599344511-819193542-1074) 
2012-07-06 13:09:24 Slp: Sco: Attempting to replace account with sid in security descriptor D:(A;OICI;KR;;;S-1-5-21-2383144575-3599344511-819193542-1074) 
2012-07-06 13:09:24 Slp: ReplaceAccountWithSidInSddl -- SDDL to be processed:  D:(A;OICI;KR;;;S-1-5-21-2383144575-3599344511-819193542-1074) 
2012-07-06 13:09:24 Slp: ReplaceAccountWithSidInSddl -- SDDL to be returned:  D:(A;OICI;KR;;;S-1-5-21-2383144575-3599344511-819193542-1074) 
2012-07-06 13:09:24 Slp: Sco: Attempting to normalize security descriptor D:(A;OICI;KR;;;S-1-5-21-2383144575-3599344511-819193542-1074) 
2012-07-06 13:09:24 Slp: Sco: Attempting to replace account with sid in security descriptor D:(A;OICI;KR;;;S-1-5-21-2383144575-3599344511-819193542-1074) 
2012-07-06 13:09:24 Slp: ReplaceAccountWithSidInSddl -- SDDL to be processed:  D:(A;OICI;KR;;;S-1-5-21-2383144575-3599344511-819193542-1074) 
2012-07-06 13:09:24 Slp: ReplaceAccountWithSidInSddl -- SDDL to be returned:  D:(A;OICI;KR;;;S-1-5-21-2383144575-3599344511-819193542-1074) 
2012-07-06 13:09:24 Slp: Prompting user if they want to retry this action due to the following failure: 
2012-07-06 13:09:24 Slp:
----------------------------------------
```

Comment: Are you running the install elevated?  (Right click -> run as administrator)  That one's bit me in the ass more times than I'd care to admit since Server 2008 came out...

Comment: Where in the install process are you getting this error?  Does this happen on every machine you try and install SQL on, or just the one machine?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried right-clicking setup.exe and saying "run as administrator"? I saw you tried installing as the local administrator, but I have still seen some wonkyness on SQL 2008 R2 installs.

Are you installing from a DVD, local copy of the files, or a network share? The installer behaves differently if it is streaming from a network share. The service pack too.

Comment: Yes, I've right-clicked and run as administrator, even created a secondary admin ID and run logged in as that administrator, same results.  This is on a local copy of the DVD that I'm running the install from.  Thanks for your assistance!

Answer (score 0):

Seen this happen for the SQL Server installer when the file is marked as coming from another computer.

Right click the installer and bring up properties. In the general tab look near the bottom for a Security note and click the [Unblock] button.

[image]